# Angular - How to reorder items in FormArray?

Tags: angular

I have a large form that contains a bunch of controls. Within this form, I have an array of form groups which are my "rules".

I need to add the ability to change the order of the rule, not only its value but its visual place in the DOM.

Here is what my setup looks like:

[image]

Each one of those rules is a component that has its own form groups etc. The order they are initially displayed is based on their current stored processing order value.

Below each rule I have a button to move the rule up or down which is what I am working on.

With reactive forms, does the index of a form group determine its position in the component UI? For example, if I wanted to move a rule up, could I change that form groups index to `currentIndex-1` and perhaps the rule above to `+1` in order to change places?

My goal here is to be able to move those components up and down on the UI. I am trying to stay away from a drag and drop library due to the amount of rules on this page.

**Update:**

Here is a plunker of my setup:

https://plnkr.co/edit/S77zywAa7l900F0Daedv?p=preview

Comment: most likely yes. But can't confirm without looking at your code. Could you show relevant template and component codes for this?

Comment: @amal - I added a plunker of the minimal setup

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are several methods on `FormArray` like `removeAt` and `insert` that can help you to achieve your goal.

**template.html**

```html
<button class="button" (click)="move(-1, i)">Move Up</button> &nbsp; 
<button class="button" (click)="move(1, i)">Move Down</button>
```

**component.ts**

```typescript
move(shift, currentIndex) {
  const rules = this.rulesForm.get('ruleData.rules') as FormArray;

  let newIndex: number = currentIndex + shift;
  if(newIndex === -1) {
    newIndex = rules.length - 1;
  } else if(newIndex == rules.length) {
    newIndex = 0;
  }

  const currentGroup = rules.at(currentIndex);
  rules.removeAt(currentIndex);
  rules.insert(newIndex, currentGroup)
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/AjYVsmxIBYRyIcyvsAxE?p=preview)**

Comment: This looks great - my plunk must differ slightly as I am getting this error `[ts] Property 'removeAt' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.`.

When I `console.log()` my parent form, this is the structure: https://image.ibb.co/jcg6WG/Screen_Shot_2017_09_28_at_10_34_54_AM.png

Do I need to cast this to something else to access it?

Comment: Yeah, i updated plunker. `const rules = this.rulesForm.get('ruleData.rules') as FormArray;`

Comment: And in your screenshoot FormArray is called `Rule` not `rules`

Comment: Thanks, this concept works as I had hoped but I didn't look into my own code enough first. My `*ngFor` thats creating these form groups and putting them into the array is looping over my data  model not the controls. So, although the actually form control is moving within the form data, my UI doesn't change. I will see if its possible to make this change to the data model and get the same result. You did what I had asked though, nice work.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a short es6 version of "move" method:

```
move(shift: number, i: number,): void {
    const { controls } = this.rulesForm.get('ruleData.rules');
    [ controls[i], controls[i+shift] ] = [ controls[i+shift], controls[i] ];
    this.rulesForm.patchValue(controls);
}
```

[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tQQo2gUr79G1gRa1)

Comment: This approach is very risky!. It changes values in controls, not the order of the controls. So eg. if you subscribe to the first control (item) in FormArray and then you move it to the second position - the subscription still be plugged into the first, not second.

Comment: There is an error here, which is related to the fact that `shift === 0` and `i === 1`, since `shift + i === i`. 
The order will be changed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Angular CDK proposes util function `moveItemInArray`;

```
import { moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

move(fromIndex: number, toIndex: number):void {
  moveItemInArray(this.rulesForm.get('ruleData.rules'), fromIndex, toIndex);
}
```