# Angular FormArray contents order

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hya,

I have the below setup:

**App.Component.Ts contents**

```
carForm: FormGroup;

constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { 
    this.carForm= this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      type: '',
      extras: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

get carExtras(): FormArray {
    return this.carForm.get('extras') as FormArray;
  }

addNewExtra() {
   this.carExtras.push(this.fb.group(new Extra());
}
```

**Extra Model**

```
export class Extra {
name: string = '';
description: string = '';
}
```

Now lets say i add 4 new Extras, the array would look as follows:

```
1. name = "Phantom Wheels", description = "Big dark wheels coz driver is overcompensating"
2. name = "Clearshield", description = "Simple tint that we overcharge customers"
3. name = "Rainbow Paint Job", description = "Leftover random paints mixed and thrown onto car"
4. name = "Slick Rims", description = "Major overcompensation"
```

I want to be able to programmatically change the order of the 4 items listed.
Say i click up button next to "Slick Rims", it will swap positions with "Rainbow Paint Job" item. If i press it again it will swap positions with "Clearshield" with result as follows.

```
1. name = "Phantom Wheels", description = "Big dark wheels coz driver is overcompensating"
2. name = "Slick Rims", description = "Major overcompensation"
3. name = "Clearshield", description = "Simple tint that we overcharge customers"
4. name = "Rainbow Paint Job", description = "Leftover random paints mixed and thrown onto car"
```

Same principle if i press the down button for the entry.

Any ideas how  to achieve this, its doing my head in on how to achieve this with a FormArray.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - How to reorder items in FormArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459266/angular-how-to-reorder-items-in-formarray)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your form array looks like this in HTML:

```
  <div formArrayName="extras">
    extras:
    <div *ngFor="let extra of carForm.get('extras').controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i" >
      <input formControlName="name">
      <input formControlName="description">
      <button (click)="moveUp(i)"> UP </button>
      <button (click)="moveDown(i)"> DOWN </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

you can create `moveUp` and `moveDown` functions to swap values at indexes (i-1, i) or (i, i+1) if it is possible

```
  moveUp(index: number) {
    if (index > 0) {
          const extrasFormArray = this.carForm.get('extras') as FormArray;
          const extras = extrasFormArray.value;
          const newExtras = this.swap(extras, index - 1, index); 
          extrasFormArray.setValue(newExtras);
    }
  }

  moveDown(index: number) {
    const extrasFormArray = this.carForm.get('extras') as FormArray;
    const extras = extrasFormArray.value;
    if (index < extras.length - 1) {
      const newExtras = this.swap(extras, index, index + 1); 
      extrasFormArray.setValue(newExtras);
    }
  }
```

swap function:

```
  swap(arr: any[], index1: number, index2: number): any[] {
    arr = [...arr];
    const temp = arr[index1];
    arr[index1] = arr[index2];
    arr[index2] = temp;
    return arr;
  }
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhcdcf

EDIT: Actually we can simplify that to single function

```
  swap(index1: number, index2: number) {
    const extrasFormArray = this.carForm.get('extras') as FormArray;
    const extras = [...extrasFormArray.value];
    if (index2 > 0 && index1 < extras.length - 1) {
      [extras[index1], extras[index2]] = [extras[index2], extras[index1]];
      extrasFormArray.setValue(extras);
    }
  }
```

which would be called with appropriate indexes

```
  <button (click)="swap(i - 1, i)"> UP </button>
  <button (click)="swap(i, i + 1)"> DOWN </button>
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9gifvd

EDIT 2 by Aeseir:

Further simplification and following DRY principle (at least attempting to):

```
get extras(): FormArray {
  return this.carForm.get('extras') as FormArray;
}


moveUp(index: number) {
  var extraTmp = this.extras.at(index);
  this.removeExtra(index);
  this.extras.insert(index-1, extraTmp);
}

moveDown(index: number) {
  var extraTmp = this.extras.at(index-1);
  this.removeExtra(index-1);
  this.extras.insert(index, extraTmp);
}

removeExtra(index: number) {
  this.extras.removeAt(index);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, i managed to develop almost exactly same solution last night after spending a whole day looking at the construct of FormArray.

Comment: I've added another edit to further simplify the solution based on what i figured out yesterday.

Comment: I changes

moveDown(index: number) {
  var extraTmp = this.extras.at(index+1);
  this.removeExtra(index+1);
  this.extras.insert(index, extraTmp);
}

Answer (score 0):

If you have FormGroup in FormArray and FormGroup also has FormArray, you'll want to just swap them around.
The next example works for me:

```
import { FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

const swap = <T>(items: T[], a: number, b: number): T[] => {
  switch (true) {
    case a < 0:
    case b < 0:
    case a > items.length - 1:
    case b > items.length - 1:
      throw new Error('Undefined swap index');
  }
  return items.map((_, i) => {
    switch (i) {
      case a:
        return items[b];
      case b:
        return items[a];
      default:
        return items[i];
    }
  });
};

export const swapFormArray = <T extends FormArray>(formArray: T, a: number, b: number): void => {
  formArray.controls = swap(formArray.controls, a, b);
  formArray.updateValueAndValidity();
};
```

usage:

```
swapFormArray(formArr, i, i - 1);
swapFormArray(formArr, i, i + 1);
```