# Angular | How to change order of FormArray?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm building an a form using FormArray in my Angular app:

```
public form = new FormGroup({
   experiences: new FormArray([])
});
```

Users can add experiences to the array:

```
addExperience(lotsOfVars) {
   const formGroup = new FormGroup({ /* creating a formgroup*/})
   (<FormArray> this.form.get('experiences')).push(formGroup);
}
```

A new requirement is to allow users change the order of  previously entered experiences:

[image]

**Question:** How is this best implemented?

Expected result (something like):

```
moveUp(i: number) {
  (<FormArray> this.form.controls['experiences']).at(i).moveUp()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - How to reorder items in FormArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459266/angular-how-to-reorder-items-in-formarray)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could just swap the controls.

```
// clone object (otherwise only pointer/reference is saved).
const temp = Object.assign({}, (<FormArray> this.form.controls['experiences']).at(i - 1).value);
(<FormArray> this.form.controls['experiences']).at(i - 1).setValue((<FormArray> this.form.controls['experiences']).at(i).value);
(<FormArray> this.form.controls['experiences']).at(i).setValue(temp);
```

for more detailed answer you could [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273499/angular-formarray-contents-order).

Answer (score 5):

You can simply remove the group from one index and insert at another:

```
let group = (<FormArray>this.form.get('address')).at(index);
(<FormArray>this.form.get('address')).removeAt(index);
(<FormArray>this.form.get('address')).insert(index,group);
```