# Angular 2+ - unable to swap 2 elements of FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I am working with FormArray of FormControls. I have an array of objects that are displayed in a table. Each object has an editable property that is displayed in a textarea. Those textareas are added to FormArray.

A user should be able to move each row up or down. To achieve that, I am swapping 2 elements of the array.

After the objects are swapped, I swap FormArray elements well, however after that FormArray elements  appear incorrectly on the page (the other object properties are swapped, but the TextAreas are not swapped). When I debug, after the objects are swapped the values in the corresponding FormArray elements remain the same as before the swap, so it looks like it is required to swap FormArray values as well.

When I try to swap just objects but not FormArray elements, everything looks fine on the page. However, when I try to update the textarea of the swapped row, save and refresh, the text in the textarea appears incorrect. Also when I try to update the textarea to invalid value, incorrect error messages are displayed (referring to the wrong row). Apparently FormArray elements were not actually swapped, though they appear swapped on the page.

From both scenarios it looks like when the objects are swapped the textarea controls are not refreshed.

The snippet of the html template I am using is:

```
<form [formGroup]="standardForm" novalidate>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container formArrayName="standardArray">
        <ng-template ngFor let-question [ngForOf]="standardQuestions" let-i="index">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <textarea formControlName="{{i}}" id="Question_{{question.Id}}" name="Question_{{question.Id}}" [maxlength]="maxQuestionTextLength"
                        class="form-control" appElasticText (blur)="saveStandardQuestion(i)"
                        [class.is-invalid]="checkForStandardError(i) "></textarea>
              <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="checkForStandardError(i)?.required">Question is required.</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

The code in the component:

```
    this.standardForm =
        this.formBuilder.group({
          standardArray: this.formBuilder.array([])
        });
      this.standardArray = this.standardForm.get('standardArray') as FormArray;
   _.each(this.standardQuestions, q => {
     this.createStandardFormArrayItem(q);
   });


createStandardFormArrayItem(question: InterviewQuestionModel) {
    const ctrl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(this.maxQuestionTextLength)]);
    this.standardArray.push(ctrl);
    ctrl.patchValue(question.Question);
  }
```

Here I a trying to swap 2 elements:

```
private swapStandard(i: number, j: number) {
    const question = this.standardQuestions[i];
    const swapQuestion = this.standardQuestions[j];
    // Here is call to the server to swap the elements

       const temp = this.standardQuestions[j];
        this.standardQuestions[j] = this.standardQuestions[i];
        this.standardQuestions[i] = temp;

// Here is the logic to swap elements of the standardArray that resulted in incorrect display on the page. 

// const c1 = this.standardArray.at(i) as FormControl;
// const c2 = this.standardArray.at(j) as FormControl;
// c1.setValue(this.standardQuestions[i].Question);
// c2.setValue(this.standardQuestions[j].Question);

      }
```

I tried to add timeout, but it is not working either:

```
setTimeout(() =>{
       const c1 = this.standardArray.at(i) as FormControl;
        const c2 = this.standardArray.at(j) as FormControl;
        c1.setValue(this.standardQuestions[i].Question);
        c2.setValue(this.standardQuestions[j].Question);
}, 500);
```

I attempted to remove both items from FormArray and insert them again setting their values from the swapped objects, but it still did not work.

Please suggest how to refresh the UI after the values of FormArray controls are swapped.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Have you check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55628204/21405520. In my case, I had to play with exact indexes but it worked.